# How to add a Google Drive directory to my computer

Tags: google-apps

I downloaded Google Drive, clicked on it and dragged the application to the Applications folder. When I clicked on it, it opened up in my browser. There was no further installation process. It didn't add a Google Drive directory to my computer. How can I add such a directory to my computer?

Comment: Did you create/sign in to your account? It won't do a thing until you do.

Comment: @Tetsujin I solved the problem and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a difference between starting the program from Launchpad and from Finder.

When I tried running the program from Launchpad, it opened up in my browser and didn't give me the option to install anything.

But when I went to the Applications folder in Finder, and ran it from there, the installer started and I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: When you install Google Drive, you must run it from the actual application in the application folder. Launchpad is just a URL shortcut.**

**To change your settings:**

1. Click Google Drive, the icon is in the menu bar at the top right of 
   In the top right, click Menu .
2. Select Preferences.

[image]

**Folder can be seen here as well:**
[image]

Comment: I got it now. I went to the Applications folder in Finder, double-clicked and then the installer started. It turns out there's a difference between running it from Launchpad and running it from Finder

Comment: lol glad you got it working, now you can use my info. Launchpad is a shortcut via URL only. Hence, me not mentioning it in my post.